# Fibonacci triangle

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, fibonacci

Given an integer n, output the following ASCII art to n rows:

```
1+1=2
  1+2=3
    2+3=5
      3+5=8
        5+8=13
```

Essentially, the first row is `1+1=2` and the nth row (1-indexed) is \$f_n + f_{n+1} = f_{n+2}\$ where \$f\$ is the Fibonacci sequence, padded so the numbers line up with the previous row.

You may instead output it infinitely. You may output a list of lines.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

### Testcase

The output for 20 should be:

```
1+1=2
  1+2=3
    2+3=5
      3+5=8
        5+8=13
          8+13=21
            13+21=34
               21+34=55
                  34+55=89
                     55+89=144
                        89+144=233
                           144+233=377
                               233+377=610
                                   377+610=987
                                       610+987=1597
                                           987+1597=2584
                                               1597+2584=4181
                                                    2584+4181=6765
                                                         4181+6765=10946
                                                              6765+10946=17711
```

Comment: So zero-indexing is allowed?

Comment: @Neil What do you mean by that? (Do you mean outputting n-1 or n+1 rows, because if so, no.)

Comment: I mean starting with the zero-indexed first Fibonacci number, i.e. `0+1=1` and working down and right from there.

Comment: @Neil That seems to go against the intent of the challenge, so I'll say no on that one.

Comment: How exactly is this a triangle?

Comment: @loopywalt Isn't really, but I couldn't think of a better name.

Comment: Fibonacci swoosh?

Comment: Is leading whitespace allowed?

Comment: @pxeger Allowed?  Seems to be *required* as I read it...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I mean constant extra leading whitespace, like this: https://gist.github.com/pxeger/768a57edc59ce03a673d1d6a943ff0d7

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 67 bytes

Outputs the sequence indefinitely.

```python
a=b=l=1
while 1:print'%*d+%d='%(l,a,b)+`a+b`;l-=~len(`b`);a,b=b,a+b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9E2yTbH1pCrPCMzJ1XB0KqgKDOvRF1VK0VbNcVWXVUjRydRJ0lTOyFROynBOkfXti4nNU8jISlB0xoobpukAxT//x8A)

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES8), 79 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,A=B=1,p)=>n?''.padEnd(p)+A+`+${B}=${B+=A}
`+f(n-1,B-A,(A+"").length-~p):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcRBCsIwEADAu88oQnbZJFiPwlYS8B8NTVKVsgm2eJH69egc5hneYZ1ej7oZKTG1lhlEO/bc64o8yFUpW0O8SYSK5Gik48fv/I/Y7YeRMojptTdOg6OuQ7skmbe7@Va8KNWmImtZkl3KDBnOJ8T2Aw)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (                   // f is a recursive function taking:
  n,                    //   n = input
  A = B = 1,            //   A, B = Fibonacci variables
  p                     //   p = padding length, initially undefined
) =>                    //
n ?                     // if n is not equal to 0:
  ''.padEnd(p) +        //   append p spaces (none if p is undefined)
  A +                   //   followed by A
  `+${B}=${B += A}\n` + //   followed by "+[B]=[B+A]\n" (A is added to B)
  f(                    //   followed by the result of a recursive call:
    n - 1,              //     decrement n
    B - A,              //     update A to the previous value of B
    (A + "")            //     add the length of A coerced to a string + 1
    .length - ~p        //     to p
  )                     //   end of recursive call
:                       // else:
  ''                    //   stop the recursion
```

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>71</s> 66 bytes

-5 thanks to [Sisyphus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243667/fibonacci-triangle/243680?noredirect=1#comment548748_243680)

```c
i,j;main(k){for(;;)printf("%*d+%d%n=%d\n",i,j=k-j,k+=j,&i,j+k+k);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9TJ8s6NzEzTyNbszotv0jD2lqzoCgzryRNQ0lVK0VbNUU1z1Y1JSZPSQeo0jZbN0snW9s2S0cNyNPO1s7WtK79/x8A)

Outputs indefinitely.

Comment: 66 bytes using `%n`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9TJ8s6NzEzTyNbszotv0jD2lqzoCgzryRNQ0lVK0VbNUU1z1Y1JSZPSQeo0jZbN0snW9s2S0cNyNPO1s7WtK79/x8A "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 25 bytes

```
≔Ｅ²¦¹ηＦＮ«Ｉ⌊η+≔⟦⌈ηΣη⟧η⟦⪫η=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU/DN7FAw0hHwVBTRyFD05orLb9IQcMzr6C0xK80Nym1SENTU6GaizOgKDOvRMM5sbhEwzczLzO3NFcjQ1MTqB4qo6StBOJAzYz2TayAqtFRCAbTsRDjocqjvfIz8zQydBSUbJU0Y4Hitf//Gxn81y3LAQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔Ｅ²¦¹η
```

Start with two `1`s.

```
ＦＮ«
```

Repeat `n` times.

```
Ｉ⌊η
```

Output the first element of the old pair.

```
+
```

Output a `+`.

```
≔⟦⌈ηΣη⟧η
```

Replace the pair with the second element and their sum.

```
⟦⪫η=
```

Output the new pair joined with `=` and move the cursor down.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 30 bytes

```
W P[xi::o'+o+:i'=i+o]x.:sX#i+1
```

Outputs forever. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhb7whUCoisyrazy1bXzta0y1W0ztfNjK_SsiiOUM7UNIYqgamF6AA)

#### Explanation

```
W P[xi::o'+o+:i'=i+o]x.:sX#i+1
                                i is 0, o is 1, x is "", s is " " (implicit)
   [                ]           Put the following in a list:
    x                            The indent: x
     i::o                        Swap i (the smaller number) with o (the larger number)
                                 and return the new value of i
         '+                      Plus sign
           o+:i                  Add i to o in-place and return the new value of o
               '=                Equals sign
                 i+o             Add i and o
  P                             Print the list (concatenating its elements by default)
W                               Loop while the list is truthy (which is always):
                          #i     Length of i
                            +1   Plus 1
                        sX       That many spaces
                     x.:         Concatenate with x in-place
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 66 bytes @emanresu A

```python
a=b=l=1
while l:=len(x:=f"{a:>{l}}+{b}=%d")-3:a,b=b,a+b;print(x%b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9E2yTbH1pCrPCMzJ1Uhx8o2JzVPo8LKNk2pOtHKrjqntla7OqnWVjVFSVPX2CpRJ8k2SSdRO8m6oCgzr0SjQjVJ8/9/AA)

#### Old [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 67 bytes

```python
a=b=l=1
while l:=len(x:=f"{a:>{l}}+{b}"):a,b=b,a+b;print(x+f'={b}')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9E2yTbH1pCrPCMzJ1Uhx8o2JzVPo8LKNk2pOtHKrjqntla7OqlWSdMqUSfJNkknUTvJuqAoM69Eo0I7Td0WKKWu@f8/AA)

Based on @dingledooper's Python 2 answer.

Comment: You can save a byte with some [cursed formatting](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9E2yTbH1pCrPCMzJ1Uhx8o2JzVPo8LKNk2pOtHKrjqntla7OqnWVjVFSVPX2CpRJ8k2SSdRO8m6oCgzr0SjQjVJ8/9/AA) :)

Answer (score 3):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), <s>90 87</s> 84 bytes

```
	N =1
N	N =M + (M =N)
	OUTPUT =P =DUPL(' ',X) M '+' N '=' M + N
	P @X N '='	:(N)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYsxC4AgFAZn/RXf9hRbgqbgQYNt@XqDgnNz5ND/x4qmg@PuvtrRzql3I@DRyoeEAJfA4q3ZS9aSwQqORTdHoKF6JFAgCIgJXy7WKJb6GzO7d10l9v4A)

Outputs infinitely, but experiences integer overflow after a short while.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
+2ÆḞ€DżṖ©;⁾+=Ɗ⁶ṁ$®¦F)Y
```

A full program that accepts an integer and prints the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATQAy/9qZWxsef//KzLDhuG4nuKCrETFvOG5lsKpO@KBvis9xorigbbhuYEkwq7CpkYpWf///zIw)**

#### How?

```
+2ÆḞ€DżṖ©;⁾+=Ɗ⁶ṁ$®¦F)Y - Main Link: integer, N
                    )  - for each V in [1..N]:
+2                     -   V add two
  ÆḞ€                  -   Fibbonacci of each of [1..V+2]
     D                 -   to decimal digits -> [[1],[1],[2],...,Digits(Fib(V+2))]
                                                call this FibDigits
             Ɗ         -   last three links as a monad - f(V):
       Ṗ               -     pop -> [1..V-1]
        ©              -       (copy this to the register)
          ⁾+=          -     ['+', '=']
         ;             -     concatenate -> [1,2,3,...,V-1,'+','=']
                                            call this Fillers
      ż                -   FibDigits zip with Fillers
                  ¦    -   sparse application...
                 ®     -   ...to indices: recall from register -> [1..V-1]
                $      -   ...action: last two links as a monad:
              ⁶        -     space character
               ṁ       -     mould like (e.g. [[1,4,4],12] -> [[' ',' ',' '], ' ']
                   F   -   flatten
                     Y - join with newlines
                       - implicit print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), [19 bytes](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte)

```
ÞF3l(:n‛+=Y∑꘍,nhL›+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnkYzbCg6buKAmys9WeKIkeqYjSxuaEzigLorIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Outputs infinitely.

```
ÞF3l                # Take the infinite list of Fibonacci numbers, and get overlapping groups of 3
    (               # Looping over that...
          Y∑        # Interleave...
      n             # The tuple of three numbers
       ‛+=          # With '+='
     :      ꘍       # Pad that with the correct amount of spaces, without popping the padding amount
             ,      # Print that
                  + # Add to the padding amount (initially 0)
              nhL›  # The length of the first number in the tuple, plus one.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <sup><s>117</s> <s>107</s> <s>103</s> <s>99</s></sup> 88 bytes

```
p="1=1"
while p:=" "*(a:=1+p.find("+"))+eval("f'{%s=}'"%p[a:].replace("=","+")):print(p)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3IwpslQxtDZW4yjMyc1IVCqxslRSUtDQSrWwNtQv00jLzUjSUtJU0NbVTyxJzNJTS1KtVi21r1ZVUC6ITrWL1ilILchKTUzWUbJV0wOqsCooy80o0CjQh5kOtgVkHAA)

Outputs infinitely.

Can probably be much improved.

Comment: How do you use ":=" in a lambda?

Comment: @Fmbalbuena What do you mean by "how"? It's the same as anywhere else

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 30 bytes

```
ÞFẎ3l⟑‛+=fY∑¥$꘍:\=ḟnḢvL₌t¯-h-£
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwiw55G4bqOM2zin5HigJsrPWZZ4oiRwqUk6piNOlxcPeG4n27huKJ2TOKCjHTCry1oLcKjIiwiIiwiMjAiXQ==)

A big cursed mess of formatting and registering.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 55 bytes

```
1=1
{`.*\+
$.&$* 
=
+
\d+.(\d+)
$&=$&$*_$1$*_
:`_+
$.&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fy9DWkKs6QU8rRptLRU9NRUuBy5ZLmysmRVtPA0hocqmo2aoAheNVDIEEl1VCPFjd//8A) Tries to output indefinitely but runs out of memory after about 50 seconds on TIO. Explanation:

```
1=1
```

Initialise the buffer with a hypothetical previous line.

```
{`
```

Repeat indefinitely.

```
.*\+
$.&$*
```

Replace up to and including the `+` with spaces. (This only applies after the first loop.)

```
=
+
```

Change the `=` into a `+`.

```
\d+.(\d+)
$&=$&$*_$1$*_
```

Append the sum of the two values in unary.

```
:`_+
$.&
```

Convert the unary to decimal and output the result.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>23</s> 22 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÌLÅfü3ε„+=.ιJ¯Oú,yнg>ˆ
```

-1 byte after being inspired by [*@JonathanAllan*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243703/52210)

Outputs the first \$n\$ lines.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ATcAyP9vc2FiaWX//8OMTMOFZsO8M8614oCeKz0uzrlKwq9Pw7osedC9Zz7Lhv//MjD/LS1uby1sYXp5)

Or a minor **22 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)** alternative:

```
ÌLÅfDü3„+=δ.ιJs€g>.¥ú»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ATgAx/9vc2FiaWX//8OMTMOFZkTDvDPigJ4rPc60Ls65SnPigqxnPi7CpcO6wrv//zIw/y0tbm8tbGF6eQ)

And the infinite sequence would be **22 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)** as well:

```
∞Åfü3vy„+=.ιJ¯Oú,yнg>ˆ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9vc2FiaWX//@KInsOFZsO8M3Z54oCeKz0uzrlKwq9Pw7osedC9Zz7Lhv//)

**Explanation:**

```python
Ì              # Increase the (implicit) input-integer by 2
 L             # Pop and push a list in the range [1,input+2]
  Åf           # Get the 0-based n'th Fibonacci value for each of these
    ü3         # Pop and push all overlapping triplets of this list
      ε        # Foreach over the triplets:
               #  (implicitly push the current triplet)
       „+=.ι   #  Intersperse it with "+" and "=" delimiters
            J  #  Join this list together to a string
       ¯       #  Push the global_array (empty by default)
        O      #  Sum it together
         ú     #  Pad the string with that many leading spaces
          ,    #  Pop and output this line with trailing newline
       y       #  Push the pair again
        н      #  Pop and push its first item
         g     #  Pop and push its length
          >    #  Increase it by 1
           ˆ   #  Pop and add it to the global_array
```

Comment: You might be able to save bytes on the infinite version by porting [my Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243713/100664) and keeping the padding amount on the stack?

Comment: @emanresuA I'm afraid not. It would be [22 bytes as well](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9vc2FiaWX//zDiiJ7DhWbDvDN2RHnigJ4rPS7OuUrDuix50L1nPiv//w). 05AB1E remembers the last value if it needs an argument and the stack is now empty, so I will have to push an explicit `0` at the start (otherwise it will use the infinite overlapping triplets list for the padding). In addition, I need an explicit `D`uplicate within the loop. That, combined with the 1 byte longer Fibonacci builtin compared to your Vyxal answer, is an alternative infinite 22-byter.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 76 bytes

```r
l=b=1
repeat{cat(sprintf("%*d+%d=%d
",l,T,b,s<-T+b));l=l+nchar(b)+1;T=b;b=s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAe88QBG23g2fbX/gBV42CRUS9RW@3mb6WEJPbemklzjfFaUbrT52XUXrPoDPpvCkUDMg4ziMAW@uFBGq6YzdswflA7JnGt9YP)

Outputs infinitely.

---

If leading whitespace is allowed:

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>74</s> 69 bytes

```r
b=1
repeat cat(sprintf("%*d+%d=%d
",F<-F+nchar(+T)+1,T,b,b<-T+(T=b)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8nWkKsotSA1sUQhObFEo7igKDOvJE1DSVUrRVs1xVY1hUtJx81G1007LzkjsUhDO0RT21AnRCdJJ8lGN0RbI8Q2SVNT8/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>102</s> <s>76</s></sup> 72 bytes

```c
b;s;f(a){for(a=b=1;s=printf("%*d+%d",s,a,b);a=b-a)printf("=%d\n",b+=a);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NckxDoAgDEDR3VMQEpJWcHBuehOXAsE4iAbciGdHFv/4X1j2EHr3VCmBYEtXAWHPK1W@y5GfBNrM0ZqoXXXiPNLgRfBHNnHL2nnLgvT2MdUpRwZUbVKjBEjT2z8)

*Saved a whopping 26 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!*
*Saved 3 bytes thanks to [m90](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104752/m90)!!!*

Outputs *forever*!

Comment: [A further improvement](https://tio.run/##NckxDoAgDEDR3VMQEpJWcHBuehOXAsE4iAbciGdHFv/4X1j2EHr3VCmBYEtXAWHPK1W@y5GfBNrM0ZqoXXXiPNLgRfBHNnHL2nnLgvT2MdUpRwZUbVKjBEjT2z8)

Comment: @m90 Nice one - thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 54 bytes

```
K`1+1=2
"$+"+`(\d+)=(\d+)$
$&¶$.%`* $1+$2=$.(*_$2*
A`$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/3zvBUNvQ1ohLSUVbSTtBIyZFW9MWTKpwqagd2qaip5qgpaBiqK1iZKuip6EVr2KkxeWYoPL/v5EBAA) No test suite because of the way the program uses history. Explanation:

```
K`1+1=2
```

Replace the input with the first line of the output.

```
"$+"+`
```

Repeat `n` times.

```
(\d+)=(\d+)$
```

Match `fₙ=fₙ₊₁` from the previous line.

```
$&¶$.%`* $1+$2=$.(*_$2*
```

Append `fₙ+fₙ₊₁=` plus their sum, with the correct amount of indent.

```
A`$
```

Since the program started with one line and appended `n` lines, it now has one line too many, so delete the last line.

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <sup><s>139</s> . . . <s>104</s></sup> 103 bytes

```bash
_()($[a=b=1];for n in `seq $1`;{ printf "%${s}s";echo -n $a+$b;$[c=a+b,s+=~${#a},a=b,b=c];echo "=$c";})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JczBCoMwDADQXwldBko7mLuGfImIJkXRS93MbqX79Srs/ngqttY6Nm2DvbByN9CyH5BgSzDZ/AHsJsrwPrb0XcDdMVsxR3Ncd3gkQPGohH1k8RrM8w/zTUq4qqAchz90jNFRaesIr2c9AQ)

Comment: Is all that whitespace necessary?

Comment: @emanresuA not sure :)

Comment: [Removed](https://tio.run/##LclBCsMgEEbhq/xYS1psCy66kjlLdMSQQDFtJjvx7FZIFt/mPQ4ytzbe7gVC1oWOu9hN64aMJcNL@kFb7wq@25L3CQOuLxnOId6lOK94ZuhgNLtP2qEiBcPqOIp0VEcWQ7pcQjX2DIH4wdR3RW0j7Lv9AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 89 bytes

```hs
l!s@[a,b,c]|[x,y,z]<-show<$>s=(l++x++'+':y++'=':z):(' '<$' ':x++l)![b,c,b+c]
f=""![1,1,2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P0ex2CE6USdJJzm2JrpCp1KnKtZGtzgjv9xGxa7YViNHW7tCW1tdW92qEkjZqltVaVppqCuo26gACSugVI6mYjRQs06SdnIsV5qtkpJitKGOoY5R7P/cxMw8BVuF3MQC33iFgtKS4JIinzyFtP8A)

`f` is a stream of lines.
*l*`!`*s* formats current line and computes next triplet *s* and leading whitespace *l*

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <sup><s>49</s> <s>47</s></sup> 45 bytes

```
liX:Y;{[ST*X`_,T)+:T;'+Y:K'=XY+:YN]oK:X;(_}g;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/PyczwirSujo6OEQrIiFeJ0RT2yrEWl070spb3TYiUtsq0i8239sqwlojvjbd@v9/Q1MA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <sup><s>66</s></sup> 65 bytes

```julia
f(a=1,b=1,n=0)=print(" "^n,"$a+$b=$(a+b)
")f(b,a+b,n-~ndigits(a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P00j0dZQJwmI82wNNG0LijLzSjSUFJTi8nSUVBK1VZJsVTQStZM0uZQ00zSSdIBMnTzduryUzPTMkmKNRE1NoAma/wE)

prints infinitely. To avoid `Int64` overflow, replace `a=1` with `a=big(1)` (+5 bytes)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>146</s> 141 bytes

```python
print("1+1=2")
a=[1,1,2]
w=2
while 1:print(" "*w+str(a[1])+"+"+str(a[2])+"="+str(a[1]+a[2]));del a[0];w+=len(str(a[0]))+1;a.append(a[0]+a[1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzBCsMgEETvfoV40m4oWXur7JeIh4UICYiVVJB8vU1NKXN684YpR11f@dF72bdctUJAssoIJo8TTjaIRla0dUtR4vM3kurW4F13zR6DAXXmIvslUn8HozJuiUmyn4NrQClmffn5VICO71xKzMtoYFz2/gE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <del>228</del> <del>226</del> 225 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to the comment of @ceilingcat

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzBqsIwEEV/ZShdTGws9i0rKbgU1K0LecgkTdtIHYPJQhS/va/Gt5jh3DvMCYZGmqabvlgTYU@OwT6i5TbAxvtXazvokOstR6FS6pE@Seq0v5d650I84af4H/GrGK4UzfAyFCysVHNwIyQ@qwZJakmFFnXdYyLJy0q81z1WspI8U4c/K1E@nT@6OGy5tY/ySj7ZML0bIZ2YVRlAtnCiCFlORa5VbrJ32d3ulsyA/u44jrNvmv4A)

```scala
object Main extends App{def f(n:Int)={def g(a:Int,b:Int,n:Int):List[(Int,Int,Int)]=n match{case 0=>Nil case _=>(a,b,a+b)::g(b,a+b,n-1)};g(1,1,n)};f(20).zipWithIndex.map{case((a,b,c),i)=>("  "*i)+s"$a+$b=$c"}.foreach(println)}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVHBTsMwDL33K56qHhIo1bZjpSFxYxJw2YEDmlCSZjQoS0sboQm0by9um45ymJAS23Ls5/fiVgkruq6S71p5PArjoI9eu6LFXV3jOwLoFHqPfdUchH8wrWeWTI4@fGEb51NMhu94yG99Y9zbDusBAuhbsi9TPxtfblyhj9lBEDyGR0CJVoMxkUKmUDyF4VjfgsWIcQW2ImM4xzXaOBHkEknIiYqH9lM03omokZUTSpmt/mAuH3hdYHumF/ruta11w0Q@1sjg/wVxoK9RZQALcha9gidj57nXQdUos9chOfJ8NnlK00zcYMnP@jArWqag4/iv7E9hw368LojPbFd/fmO14H3XuTSjSAtVspq25S1BnqKu@wE)

```scala
object Main extends App {
  
  def formatList(list: List[(Int, Int, Int)]): List[String] = {
    list.zipWithIndex.map { 
      case ((a, b, c), i) => (" " * (2 * i)) + s"$a + $b = $c"
    }
  }
  
  def fibonacciSeq(n: Int): List[(Int, Int, Int)] = {
    def fibHelper(a: Int, b: Int, n: Int): List[(Int, Int, Int)] = n match {
      case 0 => Nil
      case _ => (a, b, a + b) :: fibHelper(b, a + b, n - 1)
    }
    fibHelper(1, 1, n)
  }
  
  val formatted = formatList(fibonacciSeq(20))
  formatted.foreach(println)
}
```

Comment: It looks like `20` is hardcoded into this; you must be able to take the value as input, or output infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-mR`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>23</s> 22 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Includes a trailing space on each line of output.

```
"+= "¬ËiMg°UÃvÈùT±XÊÃ¬
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW1S&code=Iis9ICKsy2lNZ7BVw3bI%2bVSxWMrDrA&input=MjA)

```
"+= "¬ËiMg°UÃvÈùT±XÊÃ¬     :Implicit map of each U in the range [0,input)
"+= "¬                     :  Split "+= " to an array of characters
      Ë                    :  Map
       i                   :    Prepend
          °U               :      Prefix increment U
        Mg                 :      Get the Uth Fibonacci number, 0-indexed
            Ã              :  End map
             v             :  Modify the first element
              È            :  By passing it through the following function as X
               ù           :    Left pad with spaces to length
                T±         :      Increment T (initially 0) by
                  XÊ       :        Length of X
                    Ã      :  End modification
                     ¬     :  Join
                           :Implicit output joined with newlines
```